# How do I access the data array in my axios function

Tags: node.js, axios, pug

I'm trying to access the data array that has the information from the request, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

When I try to display it in my view, I get an undefined cannot read property of length;

```
const getData = () => {
    axios.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
        .then(res => {
            const data = [];
            const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
            $('.maincounter-number').each((index, element) => {
                const numberData = $(element).text();
                data[0] = {numberData: numberData};
            });
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Error fetching and parsing data: ", err);
    });

}


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const data = getData();;
    res.render('index', {title: 'Home', data: data});

});
```

Pug View

```
p #{data.dataNumbers}
```

I've also tried this function as well but I get the same issue

```
async function scrapeWorldOMeter(){
   try{
       const worldOMeterResponse = await axios.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/");
       const data = [];
       const $ = cheerio.load(worldOMeterResponse.data);
       $('.maincounter-number').each((index, element) => {
       const numberData = $(element).text();
       data[0] = {numberData: numberData};
       return data[0];
   });

   }
   catch(err){
       throw new Error(`Can't scrape WorldOMeter ${err}`)
   }
}


app.get("/", async(req, res) => {
const data = await scrapeWorldOMeter()
res.render('index', {title: 'Home', data});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your first code snippet by using promises properly,

```
const getData = () => {
    return axios
        .get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/')
        .then((res) => {
            const data = [];
            const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
            $('.maincounter-number').each((index, element) => {
                const numberData = $(element).text();
                data[0] = { numberData: numberData };
            });
            return data[0];
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error fetching and parsing data: ', err);
        });
};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
     const data = getData().then((res) => {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Home', data: data });
    });   
});
```

The problem here was that you were not returning the axios promise in getData() and also you were not chaining the response with `then` in the get route.

Your second code snippet can be fixed by using async/await properly,

```
async function scrapeWorldOMeter() {
    try {
        const worldOMeterResponse = await axios.get(
            'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
        );
        const data = [];
        const $ = cheerio.load(worldOMeterResponse.data);
        $('.maincounter-number').each((index, element) => {
            const numberData = $(element).text();
            data[0] = { numberData: numberData };
        });
        return data[0];
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(`Can't scrape WorldOMeter ${err}`);
    }
}

app.get("/", async(req, res) => {
const data = await scrapeWorldOMeter();
res.render('index', {title: 'Home', data});
});
```

The problem here was that you were returning data[0] inside the jquery each loop. You simply have to move it to the next line outside the loop